# Can we Access Complex object stored in session in Razor View .Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there a possibility of accessing complex object inside .cshtml in .net core 3.1 ? I went through most of the sites couldn't get any information on the same. On the server side i found we can do as below

```cs
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static T GetComplexData<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var data = session.GetString(key);
        if (data == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
    }

    public static void SetComplexData(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }
}
```

HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("abcd", listOfObject);

How do we access this listOfObject  which is List  in session in razor view?

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: you need extension methods (as posted in your code), of course in the razor view, you still need to use those extension methods (there will be no dictionary-style accessor).

Comment: cshtml is server rendered so you can use the same methods. however i would not advise to access it in the view, but rather in the controller and pass it to the view in Model/ViewBag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the methods above in the server side code right before returning the view. That way you can create a ViewModel to store your complex object, and return this ViewModel. Now you can access your complex object within the razor view.

EX:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var myComplexObject = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<ComplexObjectType>("abcd");

    var vM = new SomeViewModel
    {
        ComplexObject = myComplexObject
    };

    return View(vM);
}
```

Then in the view,

```
@model ProjectName.ViewModels.SomeViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

// Access it like so:
Model.ComplexObject
```